# Log all the queries before running

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Using Zend Framework I need to log my system with information containing who did what.
I want a system to log things happening in Database for update and delete queries.

Comment: Almost doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zend, but perhaps you should start here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you just want to log your queries.  You would first need to setup a Zend_Log (here is a tutorial : http://devjoe.blogspot.ca/2012/06/zendlog-tutorial-zendlogcan-be-very.html and http://devjoe.blogspot.ca/2012/06/zendlog-tutorial-part-2.html).

After your log is set up, you could add the following line to your model in the function that calls your mysql query:

```
public function simpleSelectQuery($someParam) {
    $mdl = new self(); 
    $select = $mdl->select();
    $select->where('id = ?', $someParam);
    MyApp_Logger::log('User is running query: '.$select->__toString(), Zend_Log::NOTICE);
    return $mdl->fetchAll($select); 
}
```

This would display the SELECT statement that is generated by Zend in your log file.

Comment: Thanks alot . Other people just voted down but you got my point and answered.thanks